# Google Analytics Service API - Determining if access token is expired

Tags: oauth, google-analytics

I am wondering if anyone knows a clean programmatic way of detecting a 401 response with the analytics API.  I know the underlying HTTP transport probably has it but when the call is made via Analytics object the only indicator of failure is an IOException (which could indicate an error of any type).  If there was some way to get at the JSON response that gets shown in the stack trace you could check there maybe, but right now the only thing I can think of is to parse the e.getMessage() string.  Example:

```
GaData gadata = null;
try {
    gaData = analytics.data().ga().get(
            "ga:" + profileId,
            "2012-06-01",
            "2012-06-30",
            "ga:visits")
            .execute();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    if (ioe.contains("401")) {
        System.out.println("A 401 occurred.");
    }
}
```

The reason for isolating this case is because it indicates that the access token has expired, so an alternate solution would be a better way for checking if the access token has expired.  If this can be done then the code can make a call using the API key to grant a new access token.

Comment: What framework are you using to do the call? In other words, where did you get the GaData from?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough.  This is the google analytics java services api (artifact is google-api-services-analytics v3-rev10-1.7.2-beta).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api#requests) says that the [GoogleJsonResponseException](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.6.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/json/GoogleJsonResponseException.html) will be thrown. GoogleJsonResponseException.getDetails() returns a [GoogleJsonError](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.6.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/json/GoogleJsonError.html). The GoogleJsonError.code method will return the error code (in this case the HTTP 401 ERROR).